# How do I change the name of a file to the data and time it was uploaded to the folder?

Tags: php, html, image, directory

Here is my code that allows users to upload an image to the uploads folder. Currently it won't accept a file if a file with the same name is already in the folder. For example if user 1 uploads a file called dog.jpeg and user 2 uploads a file with the same name. User 2 file will not get uploaded.

So instead of keeping the name the file already has, i wont to change the name to the time and date it was uploaded. Any ideas on how to do this?

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image. ";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo " Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo " Sorry, your file was not uploaded. ";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded. ";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file. ";
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you're using `$target_file` to define the path and name of the file.

Comment: Here is what we don't do: adapt sample code verbatimly copy&pasted from w3schools to your wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time is purely as a Unix timestamp and not as a date. If you want to convert it to a date, use the `date("Y/m/d",$time))`

replace:

```
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
 }
```

With this:

```
 if (file_exists($target_file)) {
       $time = time();         
       $target_file .= $time;
 }
```

`$target_file` is use by the move_uploaded_file later which has been appended with the timestamp.